# Is the Rocket Jumper droppable?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Does the [Rocket Jumper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Rocket_jumper) weapon drop randomly as other weapons? Or is it only obtainable trough crafting and buying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Rocket Jumper is now droppable**, as of the [June 27, 2012 patch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/June_27,_2012_Patch).

Answer (score 4):

The wiki states this item is purchase and craft only. SPUF (Steam Powered User Forums) also have no confirmed drops of this item over a month after the MANN-conomy update.

[Rocker Jumper WIKI](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Rocket_Jumper)

Comment: Damn! The same page that I linked. I feel stupid now. =)